# Visualizing image array

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am new to computer vision and I have been exploring gaussian pyramid. I got the algorithm but I am still cannot visualize it correctly.

Here is my code,

```
    #pyr is the output from gaussian method and it is a list.
    rows, cols = pyr[0].shape
    composite_image = np.zeros((rows, cols))

    composite_image[:rows, :cols] = pyr[0]
    print(composite_image.shape)
    i_row = 0
    for p in pyr[1:]:
       print(len(pyr[1:]))
       n_rows, n_cols = p.shape[:2]
       print(composite_image[i_row:i_row + n_rows, cols:cols + n_cols].shape)
       composite_image[i_row:i_row + n_rows, cols:cols + n_cols] = p
       i_row += n_rows

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(composite_image)
plt.show()
```

I got this error of the composite_image and p are of different shape. But I cannot fix it.
That's what I got from printing these,

```
  print(len(p))
  #469
  print(n_cols)
  #537
  print(n_rows) 
  #469
```

Why the shape for composite_image become (469,0). What did I do wrong?

I appreciate your help in this.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-266-932a6e524503> in <module>
      9     n_rows, n_cols = p.shape[:2]
     10     print(composite_image[i_row:i_row + n_rows, cols:cols + n_cols].shape)
---> 11     composite_image[i_row:i_row + n_rows, cols:cols + n_cols] = p
     12     i_row += n_rows
     13 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (469,537) into shape (469,0)
```

Comment: `len(p)` only tells you the first dimension.  `len(p[0])` would be 537.

Comment: Put another way, `len(p)` and `p.shape` are not the same thing.

Comment: general advice: simplify your code. this looks messy. please review [mre] for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

In line `11`, where you're attempting to broadcast the input array `p` into `composite_image`, I believe your index **slicing** is wrong. Specifically, in:

```
composite_image[i_row:i_row + n_rows, cols:cols + n_cols] = p
```

you're going from 0 (`i_row`) to 0+469 (`i_row + n_rows`) along the **rows**; whereas you're going from 537 (`cols`) to 537+537 (`cols + n_cols`) along the **columns**, and this is where it's giving you the error (basically an empty array, since you're going from the end to the end; going no where).

So what you should do is define `i_col = 0` to index your columns, the same way you defined `i_row` to index the rows.